# Subset dataframe based on duplicate values in different columns per row

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a list of pairwise comparisons of closely related isolates, one element of the list looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Isolate1 = c("s1", "s2", "s2"), Ward1.x = c("1_1", "3_3", "3_3"), Ward1.y = c("NA", "2_1", "2_1"), Ward1.z = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
           Isolate2 = c("s3", "s1", "s3"), Ward2.x = c("2_1", "1_1", "2_1"), Ward2.y = c("NA", "NA", "NA"), Ward2.z = c("NA", "NA", "NA"))

  Isolate1 Ward1.x Ward1.y Ward1.z Isolate2 Ward2.x Ward2.y Ward2.z
1       s1     1_1      NA      NA       s3     2_1      NA      NA
2       s2     3_3     2_1      NA       s1     1_1      NA      NA
3       s2     3_3     2_1      NA       s3     2_1      NA      NA
```

And I now want to find out, if there are pairwise comparisons where both isolates were sampled from the same ward. Hence, I want to check, if there are any duplicates between columns Ward1.x-Ward1.z and Ward2.x-Ward2.z.

So my output should  be a dataframe that only includes the last row of df, as Ward1.y and Ward2.x are identical, like this:

```
  Isolate1 Ward1.x Ward1.y Ward1.z Isolate2 Ward2.x Ward2.y Ward2.z
3       s2     3_3     2_1      NA       s3     2_1      NA      NA
```

I know how to subset a dataframe based on equality of two columns, but how can I check for equality between multiple columns?

Comment: Can you show the expectedoutput

Comment: @akrun I updated the question, hope its now more clearer what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `apply` would be to filter rows where there is atleast one non-NA value which is common in `"Ward1"` and `"Ward2"` columns.

```
col1 <- grep("^Ward1", names(df))
col2 <- grep("^Ward2", names(df))

df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(na.omit(x[col1]) %in% na.omit(x[col2]))), ]

#  Isolate1 Ward1.x Ward1.y Ward1.z Isolate2 Ward2.x Ward2.y Ward2.z
#3       s2     3_3     2_1      NA       s3     2_1      NA      NA
```

---

Using similar logic with `dplyr` and `tidyr` we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -starts_with("Iso"), -row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  filter(any(na.omit(value[grep("Ward1", key)]) %in% 
             na.omit(value[grep("Ward2", key)]))) %>%
  spread(key, value)

# A tibble: 1 x 9
# Groups:   row [1]
#  Isolate1 Isolate2   row Ward1.x Ward1.y Ward1.z Ward2.x Ward2.y Ward2.z
#  <chr>    <chr>    <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 s2       s3           3 3_3     2_1     NA      2_1     NA      NA
```

---

We can also use `intersect`

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) length(na.omit(intersect(x[col1], x[col2])))) > 0, ]
```